# Using JOIN with multiple LIKES

Tags: mysql, join

I have made a search field which sends 2 values:

1. Phone number
2. Car registration number

Both fields are required and unique. Phonenumber is in table A, Car registration number is in table 2. The tables are joined on PersonID. Which is primary and unique and table 1. And not primary and unique in Table 2, but is identical in the value.

I am using SELECT, to make sure, this is a match, if the phone number and car registration number don't belong to the same person, i'm gonna echo The inserted data is not correct.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Person 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Car on Car.PersonID 
WHERE Phonenumber LIKE ".$_POST['phonenumber']." AND 
WHERE Carregnumber LIKE ".$_POST['carregnumber'].";
```

This won't give me any result.

I have also tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Person 
WHERE Phonenumber LIKE ".$_POST['phonenumber']." 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Car on Car.PersonID 
WHERE Carregnumber LIKE ".$_POST['carregnumber'].";
```

Both fields are defined with $_POST. When i just use:  `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Phonenumber LIKE ".$_POST['phonenumber']."` it will give me results.

I am kinda new with JOINS, and I've through some tutorials which tells me the difference between INNER, OUTER and LEFT JOINS. So I'm not totally sure if I'm doing it okay (Well i guess not, or else i would have got data)

Am i in the right direction, or do i have to use a query similar query which i found on Stack Overflow:

```
SELECT airline, flt_no, fairport, tairport, depart, arrive, fare
FROM (SELECT * FROM flights
    INNER JOIN airports
    ON flights.fairport = airports.code
    WHERE (airports.code = '?' OR airports.city='?')) AS matches
INNER JOIN airports
ON matches.tairport = airports.code
WHERE (airports.code = '?' OR airports.city = '?')
```

I have tried to edit above query to my own situation, but gives me blank results too.

EDIT: Thanks to the comments i have adjusted my Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Person
INNER JOIN Car on Car.PersonID = Person.PersonID 
WHERE BSNNummer = ".$_POST['phonenumber']."
AND Kenteken = ".$_POST['carregnumber']."
```

This query still gives me blank results, i have followed the instructions from the comments, i see what i did wrong, but unfortunately it looks like i still have got an incomplete query.

Comment: In your first query, you should say WHERE x and y (not WHERE x and WHERE y).  You will also get a lot of comments here about sql injection attacks - inserting an arbitrary form values directly into your sql is a big security risk.

Comment: Thank you, I've just tried, but still gives me blank results. I am aware of the security risk, this is more for me to understand working with the JOIN, after that i'm going to work on the security risk.

Comment: Okay - lots of other potential issues.  Your JOIN needs to include both tables.  So, something like ON Person.PersonID = Car.PersonID.  Also, right now you have an outer join (which says that you want all matching Person records, but only Car records that match the join.  But, then you have the Car table in your WHERE clause which makes an implicit INNER JOIN out of it.  So, I think you want an INNER JOIN between the two tables.  Finally, the LIKE clause is used to match a pattern (which would include some wildcard(s)).  So, why not just equality with =

Comment: ...AND, if Phonenumber and Carregnumber are character data, you would need to quote the values (like you see in the second example)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i have folllowed up your instructions, but still am getting blank results. I think i'm missing the points somewhere..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to pull some of my comments above into an answer here so I can provide more formatting, etc...

A well formed query for what you are trying to do, might look like this:

```
SELECT
    Person.PersonID
    , Person.Phonenumber
    , Car.Carregnumber
FROM
    Person INNER JOIN
    Car ON Person.PersonID = Car.PersonID
WHERE
    Person.PhoneNumber = '123-456-7890'
AND Car.Carregnumber = '123456'
```

Several important points:

1. In the select, it isn't always necessary, but is a good idea to specify columns with their table prefix.  The DB can handle just names if they don't conflict between tables, but using the prefix future-proofs your query against certain changes that could break it in the future.
2. In the JOIN, we have to specify how to join both tables
3. Also with the join, since we need to match values from both tables, we'll make this an INNER JOIN.  Even if we made it an outer join, including both tables in the WHERE would make an implicit inner join anyway.
4. In the WHERE, we use the equals operator (not LIKE).  We care about a specific value - not if something matches a pattern.
5. Also in the WHERE, if the fields we are comparing are character data, the values need to be in single quotes.  I don't know the types of your data, so this may not apply.

What I think you should Do - Try to build a query with hard-coded values (like the one above) and get that working.  Then, introduce your variable values and go from there.  Finally, use parameters (like in your second example) to avoid sql injection.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is very clear.. It helped me having an other view at the situation.. Especially your last comment about first building hard-coded values has made me realize i had to start with that in the beginning.. Also, your other comments, very helpfull, my data is being gathered right now!